# cupsfilter: Unable to determine MIME type of ““??”.**

Tags: command-line, unix, file-conversion

I'm trying to convert html files to pdf files using the following command line

```
for file in *.html; do /usr/sbin/cupsfilter “$file” > $file.pdf; done
```

But I got the message as below and empty pdf files

```
cupsfilter: Unable to determine MIME type of ““??”.**
```

Could you please point out the syntax error that I made in command line.

I'm currently using Mac OS X 10.11.3

Comment: Wrong and missing quotes? At least `for file in *.html ; do /usr/sbin/cupsfilter "$file" > "$file".pdf ; done` works!

Comment: Thanks klanomath. But I still get the same error message as mentioned above and no pdf output files at all.

Comment: I guess your website_name.html.pdf is empty, am I right?

Comment: my pdf files is zero bytes. No clue!

Comment: Hmm remove any 0 byte file containing hmtl (or htm) before executing the command; even those with the name *.html.pdf

Answer (score 2):

## Quotes: “ versus "

You are using 'typographers' quotes instead of 'regular' quotes.
Try this line:

```
for file in *.html; do /usr/sbin/cupsfilter "$file" > "$file".pdf; done
```

*note the difference in quotation*

Comment: Thanks CousinCocaine for pointing out this typo. I just figured it out myself a minutes ago.

Comment: I wish I could read your answer sooner than I figured it out myself :). It was driving me nut. Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Bob for the correct use of quotes read: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash